# Asked Question, Got closed. Seems to meet with Guidelines, how to re-ask

Tags: discussion

***This is the question in question: [Defining the word Enterpriser](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/367634/214511)***

I asked this yesterday, and gave the information for the question that seemed relevant to me.  However the comments seem to be that I should provide links and information for things only peripherally linked to the question in question.  (specifically links to how "Entrepreneur" has negative social/cultural connotation in my area)

I've read through the guide on asking question relevant to this forum, and as far as I can understand my question falls within the guidelines.  However since it's been closed I'm left wondering how to improve the question.

Couple people clarify or expound on the guide or rules to help me better understand what is wrong with my question.

Or is it just 'back lash' because I suggested that 'entrepreneur' has negative connotations in my social/cultural environment?

Comment: Personally, my close-vote was due to the question not including any prior research. I'll vote to re-open if you tell us what resources you already checked (e.g. which thesauruses, what you googled), what words you found, and for each of those words, what you found unsatisfactory, so we have a better sense of what will work and won't work. That's what the "insufficient research" banner and link is telling you. Others have voted under the "show us an example sentence" banner, so you'll probably want to include one of those (not a trivial one, like "A synonym for entrepreneur is ____") as well.

Comment: Alright, I'm not sure if this should be done in a discussion thread or not, but I'm sure this can be moved there if needs be.

Comment: I see no need for a discussion thread, why do you bring it up? Anyway, the close-banner under your Q has two links, and you should modify your Q to satisfy both of them: *[show your research](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/5039)* and *[pre-requisites for a single-word-request question](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info)* (see, in particular, the "checklist" at the bottom of that tag wiki). In general, it also helps if you engage with and respond to people and questions asked in the comments under your Q.

Comment: User error on the above, I had more to write but hit enter instead of shift+enter and it posted my comment.

I meant to continue with:  The Research I did; I went to Google, did a define: entrepreneur, noticed the 'enterpriser' option and felt that it was a better fit for my needs.  Looked at the roots of Entrepreneur and kept them in mind so my selected work would include them/their meaning. Googled 'define:enterpriser' no results only those for enterprise, looked at the roots and meanings of enterprise.  felt that it fit with the definition I wanted.

Comment: Googled more looking specifically for a dictionary meaning of enterpriser, however met with none, only meanings for enterprise.  Which is when I came here to ask, since I had run aground with the word and wanted to get a fuller understanding of it. (Also, enterpriser is marked as incorrect in every editor i have typed it into so far.)

Comment: As for the sentence I wanted to use it in:  https://www.kickstarter.com/profile/tolmera/about  "Software Developer - Enterpriser - Human"

Comment: But you're not looking for the *definition* of *entrepreneur*, you're looking for *synonyms*, so googling *define entrepreneur* is not sufficient research. You need, at a minimum, to check a thesaurus, as well as google "synonyms for entrepreneur*, show us the complete list of words you found and considered, and for each unsatisfactory word, why it doesn't satisfy you. SE isn't here to do basic research for you, a skill which requires no expertise in English. We're here to help you solve the stickier problems he standard reference works can't, and for hat we need more details.

Comment: Oh and engagement, yes I failed on that, I asked this question last night, have since been to bed and woke up to find it closed.  I may talk in my sleep, but I have yet to develop the ability to browse the web in my sleep.

Comment: Also, you should be adding all this information into your original question, so it stands on its own and can be re-opened. Not here in comments on this Meta question. For example, someone in the comments of your original Q asked "did you even look up *enterpriser*?"; editing in the fact that you found that word in a google definition would help, as would demonstrating how you want about answering your own question about whether it has one `e` or two (what makes you ask that, and what do the standard reference works have to say about it)?

Comment: Ok, Thank you that's actually helpful, I see how my question is being read by someone not in my head.  I intended my question is an 'Is this synonym' a reasonable synonym, but I have worder my question 'Is there a synonym'  which totally changes the premise of the question and explains why people have recieved it so badly.  Now I can actually fix it.  Thank you.

Comment: You should still engage with the people in the comments under the original Q. Most of them will not see this meta-Q, and certainly no one who comes after them and finds your original Q will ever see this Meta-W, leaving their questions and comments unresolved and unaddressed in future reader's eyes.

Comment: Literally all the comments I've left here were intended to be helpful. I am not trying to be snarky at all. I have a place in my heart for people who come back to their question and have a sincere desire to improve it and respond the the community's feedback. Not sure what made you think only some of my comments were "actually helpful".

Comment: Sorry again, not what I meant, they are all helpful, but the comment "But you're not looking for the definition of entrepreneur, " was the most helpful.  It's specific to 'why' and directly apply-able.

Comment: Nice edit. I have voted to re-open, and upvoted. Thanks for your cooperation and good faith.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question has been edited by OP (thank you), re-opened by the community, upvoted, and has already attracted an answer.

Comment: **Update:** It has now been re-closed by a user and a mod as *primarily opinion-based*.

Answer (score 5):

I'm extremely tempted to vote-to-close again, for "Show your research". The question as it currently reads says:

> Looked for enterpriser without success, online dictionaries don't have a listing for it (And I don't own a physical dictionary)

All I can say is that you can't be very skilled at internet research. I typed "enterpriser" into [google](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=enterpriser), and the first four results are dictionary definitions of the word!